# CSS resources blocking by Spring Security for non authorized requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using spring boot, my CSS resources are located in .../src/main/resources/static and i have WebSecurityConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/registration", "/static/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .logout()
                    .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService)
                .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
    }
}
```

and MvcConfig class:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }
}
```

When i logged in css resources are activated. 
I have access to my templates when i'm not logged in.

Why CSS resources blocking for non authorized request?

Sorry for my English. I'll very grateful for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/control").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/register", "/login_auth", "/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/img/*.jpg", "/*.js", "/*.css").permitAll()...
```

i did this to access the files in the root static folder. 
if you got em under folders do this instead:

```
.antMatchers("/img/**", "/js/**", "/css/**").permitAll()
```

Comment: I understood that i've wrong path describing for static folder: antMatchers("/", "/registration", "/*.css").permitAll(). Now it's works. Thx alot!